# What is the cause of LIBRARY_MANAGEMENT_FAILED while trying to run notebook with custom library on synapse?

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, spark-packages

Today when we've tried running our notebooks defined in synapse, we've received constantly error: 'LIBRARY_MANAGEMENT_FAILED'. We are using approach from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-manage-python-packages#storage-account to manage custom libraries, and it was working fine up until this point. Additionally, we've tried separate method of providing spark pool with custom library and tried to use workspace packages, but after 10 minutes of loading custom package, it timesouts with failure.

When we are removing python folder completely from storage, sparkpools run notebooks normally.

Yesterday everything was working properly. The problem also could not be in custom library, because it does not work even with empty python folder.

Comment: Raise a support case through the Azure Portal.  Report back here the outcome in case it’s of use to future issues.

Comment: Did you get a chance to open a support case?

Comment: Yes, there were issues on the Microsoft side, it started working next day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were issues on Microsoft side, which were resolved and it started working next day.